# SignalR combined with WebApi

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I'm making a proof of concept for SignalR. Basically I followed the tutorial from this website: [Tutorial: Getting Started with SignalR 2](https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr) and I'm trying to send messages to the frontend from a WebApi in a different project.

The javascript code is as followed:

```
$(function () {
        // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
        var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
        // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
        chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
            // Html encode display name and message.
            var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();
            var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();
            // Add the message to the page.
            $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + encodedName
                + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodedMsg + '</li>');
        };
        // Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                // Call the Send method on the hub.
                chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment.
                $('#message').val('').focus();
            });
        });
    });
```

The code for my Hub:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        // Call the broadcastMessage method to update clients.
        Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
    }
}
```

When I build this the code it works just like the example in the link above. However when I try to send messages from another project with the following code, it won't work:

```
public class MyMessageHandler : IHandleMessages<MyMessage>
{
    static ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger<MyMessageHandler>();

    public Task Handle(MyMessage message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
    {
        log.Info($"Message received: {message.Name}");

        var hub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();
        hub.Clients.All.Send("Admin", "stop the chat");
        return Task.Delay(0);
    }
}
```

When I run this code the frontend is running on this link/port: `http://localhost:8854/index.html` and the webapi on this link/port: `http://localhost:8387/api/values`.

I feel like I am missing one final thing, but numerous Google results couldn't help me. Does anybody know how I can fix this?

Comment: IHandleMessages is a nservicebus concept right?
So does second peace of code located at the *same* app instance that your hub?
If you want `ChatHub` to be available at several app instances, then you should use signalr backplane.

Comment: @IgorLizunov IHandleMessages is indeed an NServiceBus concept. The first two code blocks are on one app instance and the last code block is on a different app instance. Do you mean this with signalr backplane? https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-in-signalr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we outlined from comments, you have two app instances on the server side.

Your hub is in one instance: `public class ChatHub : Hub`.
And this call is in another: `GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();`.

So second hub instance does not equals instance of the hub with connected clients.

To solve this issue, you need configure [backplane](https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-in-signalr) for signalr. It allows same hub to be used in different instances of the server. I recommend to use SQL server option instead of Azure/Redis.

Another solution is to stop use server-side hub in the second instance. And use client C# signalR code to connect to the first one instance (and hub).

Comment: I solved my problem by following your link. I wasn't able to get it working with SQL server but i got it working with the Azure Service Bus implementation. Thank you @igor-lizunov